# Node-RED Tail and http response

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, iot, node-red

I'm trying to make a IoT application on my Raspberry Pi.
I'm using Node-RED, it's quite easy but now I'm stuck

I have an issue with Tail (storage).
I receive the correct from the Tail function but I can't display it on my webpage.

Please have a look at my printscreen, the debug shows the correct text. But the webpage isn't. I think I'm missing something, but I can't find what.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2sLT.png

As I said, the debug output is correct, but the webpage isn't.
If you need other info please ask. Still trying to find my way in Node Red.

Sincerely,
Brecht

Comment: I have no experience whatsoever with `node-red`, but it looks like you're stringifying an object instead of using (perhaps?) a particular property of it. Is there actual code that you're written to display the object on the webpage? If so, please show it.

Comment: @robertklep, thanks for your response.
It was indeed a object because i was doing it wrong, but I solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, it was indeed something stupid.

I had to save the incoming data in a global variable.
And then later change the message.payload in that global variable.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/seEPx.png